# Let A, B, C be three sets. Prove that if $B$ \ $C$ $⊆A^c$ then $A ∩B ⊆C$ .

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I really confused about this question.

I know that If $x\in B$ and $x\notin C \implies x\in A^c \implies x\notin A$ but how do I use this fact to prove that $ A \cap B \subseteq C$.

Also can someone give me a general idea on how to solve these types of questions. I like to think that I have a good grasp on elementary set theory. Set identities such as union, intersection, cartesian product, but when I see questions like these, I have a really hard time even understanding what the question is asking a lot of the time. Thank you.

Comment: Drawing a picture would be a good start. It doesn’t prove anything, but it will probably give you some useful insight.

Answer (score 1):

First, divide $B$ into two disjoint subsets
$B = (B \cap C^c) \cup (B \cap C)$

Since the two subsets are disjoint:
$A \cap B = (A \cap (B \cap C^c)) \cup (A \cap (B \cap C))$

Now, since $(B \cap C^c) \subseteq A^c$, we have
$A \cap (B \cap C^c) = \emptyset$

So
$A \cap B = A \cap B \cap C$
which implies that $A \cap B \subseteq C$

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches to solving this problem.

**Approach 1.** Let's first write out what we want to show:
$$
\text{$x \in A$ and $x \in B$} \implies x \in C.
$$
So suppose $x$ is an element of both $A$ and $B$. Our goal is to see if we can use the knowledge we already know ($x \in B$ and $x \not\in C \implies x \not\in A$) to prove that $x \in C$. One way to proceed is to assume that $x\not\in C$, and try to derive a contradiction. Can you finish the proof from here?

**Approach 2.** Sometimes, the problem can be solved by using properties of unions, intersections, etc., and you can avoid working with a specific element $x$. We already know that
$$
B \setminus C \subseteq A^c.
$$
We want to show that $A \cap B \subseteq C$, so we would like to get “$A \cap B$” on one side of this inclusion. An idea you might have to achieve this is to intersect each side of this equation by $A$ to get
$$
A \cap B \setminus C \subseteq A^c \cap A = \varnothing.
$$
Can you finish the proof from here?